# A way to disable Multipart / MTOM in webservice return

Tags: xml, web-services, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm connecting to a Fusion / Oracle Cloud ERP WebService with PL/SQL procedures, one using the APEX API APEX_WEB_SERVICE and the other using the UTL_HTTP package.

When testing the web service request and response with SOAPUI, it returns a XML and one of the tags is another XML encoded in base64 becoming one big string encoded.

Using the PL/SQL procedures, the web service answers the request with the XML, but decoding the secondary XML, and informing the http headers for the multipart content, so that it become impossible to use the function make_request from the APEX_WEB_SERVICE API (since the function's return is XMLTYPE correctly formed), and demanding a lot of work to "clean" the clob return from the UTL_HTTP package.

Analysing the SOAPUI properties, I can see there is some properties refering to Enable (or not) MTOM, Force (or not) MTOM, Disable Multiparts, etc.

Is there a http header or any type of argument that I can send to Disable Multiparts / MTOM?

My code

APEX_WEB_SERVICE API:

```
create or replace procedure prc_teste_webservice is
  l_envelope  CLOB;
  l_xml       XMLTYPE;
  l_result    VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_result_clob clob;
  v_txt    VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

  -- Build a SOAP document appropriate for the web service.
  l_envelope := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ucm="http://www.oracle.com/UCM">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ucm:GenericRequest webKey="cs">
         <ucm:Service IdcService="GET_FILE">
            <ucm:Document>
               <ucm:Field name="dID">33333</ucm:Field>
            </ucm:Document>
         </ucm:Service>
      </ucm:GenericRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

  l_xml := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_request(
    p_url      => 'https://host/idcws/GenericSoapPort',
    p_action   => 'GenericSoapOperation', 
    p_username => '*************',
    p_password => '*************',
    p_wallet_path => 'file:c:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\wallet\',
    p_wallet_pwd => '************',
    p_envelope => l_envelope
  );

  l_result_clob := 'abcdefghij';

  -- Display the whole SOAP document returned.
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_xml=' || l_xml.getClobVal());
  l_result_clob := l_xml.getClobVal();
  l_xml := xmltype.createxml(replace(replace(replace(replace(l_xml.getClobVal(), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'), chr(13), ''), chr(10), ''));


  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_xml=' || l_result_clob);

END prc_teste_webservice;
```

UTL_HTTP:

```
create or replace procedure prc_wallet2 is
  l_envelope  CLOB;
  l_xml       XMLTYPE;
  l_result    VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_result_clob clob;
  v_txt    VARCHAR2(32767);
    soap_respond  CLOB;
    http_req      utl_http.req;
    http_resp     utl_http.resp;
    resp          XMLType;
    soap_err      exception;
    v_code        VARCHAR2(200);
    v_msg         VARCHAR2(1800);
    v_len number;
    v_txt Varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  -- Build a SOAP document appropriate for the web service.
  l_envelope := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ucm="http://www.oracle.com/UCM">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ucm:GenericRequest webKey="cs">
         <ucm:Service IdcService="GET_FILE">
            <ucm:Document>
               <ucm:Field name="dID">33333</ucm:Field>
            </ucm:Document>
         </ucm:Service>
      </ucm:GenericRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

  -- Make a HTTP request and get the response.
  utl_http.set_wallet('file:c:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\wallet\', Null);
--  l_http_request  := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('https://www.google.com');
    http_req:= utl_http.begin_request
              ( 'https://host/idcws/GenericSoapPort'
              , 'POST'
              , 'HTTP/1.1'
              );
    UTL_HTTP.set_authentication(http_req, '******************', '*****************');
    utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(l_envelope));
    utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', 'urn:GenericSoap/GenericSoapOperation');
    utl_http.write_text(http_req, l_envelope);


  http_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(http_req);

  -- Loop through the response.
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      UTL_HTTP.read_text(http_resp, l_result_clob);
      pkg_java.java_file_clob('c:\temp\teste1.txt', l_result_clob);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
      UTL_HTTP.end_response(http_resp);
  END;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_HTTP.end_response(http_resp);
    RAISE;

end prc_wallet2;
```

Comment: any luck ?? even i want to get the data from UCM using any lang